# Using mget to download multiple files from sftp

Tags: sftp

I have some `R` code, and at one part, I'm connecting to an sftp and trying to download some files. The files that need to be downloaded are determined by the R code and can either be only one or multiple. I'm trying to use `mget` to download the files, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
sftp> mget abc.PDF  def.PDF ghi.PDF
Fetching /abc.PDF to def.PDF
```

It is only downloading abc.PDF and storing it as def.PDF on the local directory instead of downloading all three files. What am I doing worng?

Comment: Is sftp a hard requirement? Would scp suffice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mget` works with a glob for the "source file" portion of the arguments (at least in OpenSSH version 7.3):

```
sftp> ls *.pdf
foo.pdf                   bar.pdf                   
sftp> mget *.pdf
Fetching /home/jdoe/bar.pdf to bar.pdf
Fetching /home/jdoe/foo.pdf to foo.pdf
sftp>
```

You will instead need to loop over the files somehow and fetch them one-by-one if a glob get catches too many.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work because OpenSSH's `sftp` doesn't support that. It's `mget` is the same as `get` (in fact, `mget` isn't even documented in `help` or the manpage), and takes only one remote file name argument (though that argument can be a glob).

So, to use the OpenSSH SFTP client, you'll need to issue one `get` per file. Alternatively, you could use a different SFTP client (for example, `lftp` has an `mget` that works like you want). Or (thanks to Gilles for the reminder) you might find it more convenient to use sshfs (via FUSE) and then use normal file copy commands (`cp`, or whatever R has built in).

Comment: +1 and my eternal thanks for the `lftp` pointer.